# Emails wont send when images inside the HTML content PHP

Tags: php, html-email

I'm using normal php `mail()` function to send emails. This works fine on localhost.

But in the online when i try to send a mail with images in the body with `<img ../>` tag the email won't go. Actually the mail function return true. Even though my inbox won't get any.

WHen I remove the `<img>` tags and try , emails are receiving to the inbox.

Please help

Thank you

```
$this->checkAuth();

//headers
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . ' <' . $from . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $from . ' ' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$this->_exit();
```

Comment: **Please show what you have tried so far...**

Comment: What does your logs say? Server's logs says mail was sent? Your mail server's logs shows it was there and got dropped as spam or from any other reason?

Comment: it is not my server actually. it is one of my client and I don't have cpanel access. only I know is it is on rackspace. I also thought that way. but why it only did when have images inside the body?

Comment: I tried with PHP mailer and wp_mail function both (it is on wordpress) .. same result. I just revealed this is because of the images

Comment: **First of all, have a look in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#105661)** about sending mails with `mail()`. Furthermore I'd recommend **not** using the native mail function, but something like [**SwiftMailer**](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead! This will help you immensely...

Comment: I'll try with SwiftMailer, this is the first time this kind of thing happend

Comment: @user2703358 Ok, nice you consider trying it. I've posted an answer containing an example of how to implement SwiftMailer. Have a look at it :-)

Comment: Did my answer help you out? Don't forget to vote / mark as accepted... See ["Why is voting important?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

would be helpful if we could see your code but I'm gonna go out on a limb here and ask you to check your spam folder and make sure the image tags are formatted corectlly and that the email script contains no errors.

also here's a helpful link http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Are you only sending a html mail?

Some mail scanners do not allow html only mail and need a plain text mail too, perhaps because you are sending an image it gets reported as spam.
This can block your mail from being send and as far as php is concerned it has been send.

Take a look at: http://kevinjmcmahon.net/articles/22/html-and-plain-text-multipart-email-/

Or the code:

```
//specify the email address you are sending to, and the email subject
$email = 'email@example.com';
$subject = 'Email Subject';

//create a boundary for the email. This 
$boundary = uniqid('np');

//headers - specify your from email address and name here
//and specify the boundary for the email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Your Name \r\n";
$headers .= "To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";

//here is the content body
$message = "This is a MIME encoded message.";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

//Plain text body
$message .= "Hello,\nThis is a text email, the text/plain version.
\n\nRegards,\nYour Name";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

//Html body
$message .= "
 Hello,
This is a text email, the html version.

Regards,
Your Name";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

//invoke the PHP mail function
mail('', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the emails you send containing the image tags are sent to your spam mailbox.

Are you using some mail provider like gmail? They mostly throw *untrusted* messages directly into the spam folder. With untrusted I mean accounts which are freshly registered.

It's not something new that mails sent with PHP's native `mail()` function cause the messages to be detected as spam. It's the way php prepares the message headers.

So, using a php mail library like **SwiftMailer** is the way to go. It provides you with good customization options and contains functionality that'll make sending mails with attachments a lot easier.

**Check it out:** http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-files

Here's an example of how to use SwiftMailer for sending an email message with an image attachment:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
  ->setUsername('your username')
  ->setPassword('your password');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

// Give the message a subject
->setSubject('Your subject')

// Set the From address with an associative array
->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))

// Set the To addresses with an associative array
->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))

// Give it a body
->setBody('Here is the message itself')

// And optionally an alternative body
->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html');

// Add the attachment
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/path/to/image.jpg'));

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

*Give it a try.*